# how to save html form input data in .txt file by using a php script?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
        $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 
        file_put_contents('test.log',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); // log to test.log (make sure that file is writable (permissions))
        header('Location: http://www.google.com/search?q='.$txt); // google as example (use your confirmation page here)
        exit();
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

ok so i found this code on this previous post i changed the input name as on my website, but i only a get blank page when i use this php script i just get a white page where can i find the .txt file which saves the input, i need to submit my project am only left with saving my data on .txt file and unable to do that , can any one help ?

Comment: Well you have several issues. **(1)** If this is all the markup you have, it's invalid HTML. **(2)** I doubt you're redirect page is the Google search results with a query parameter of your text. **(3)** The file will be saved in the same directory as the `.php` page that you're viewing. You'll need to ftp or ssh to get it or write a script that will let you download the file.

Comment: 1) i did write the rest of the body for this php script, secondly yea exactly it doesn't so can you tell which would exactly do that ?

Comment: i meant which code should i write that saves the form input to a separate file or let me download the file which ever way possible

Comment: you guys help me out please